# How to use the AssemblyName property of XmlnsDefinitionAttribute

Tags: .net, xaml

I am trying to reference an assembly, A, in XAML from another assembly. A is built in .NET v2 so it cannot have the XmlnsDefinitionAttribute applied to it internally. Rather than reference the assembly in XAML by using

```
<UserControl xmlns:a="clr-namespace:Namespace.In.A;assembly=A" />
```

all the time, I would like to use the AssemblyName attribute of [XmlnsDefinitionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute.aspx), such as

```
<Assembly: XmlnsDefinitionAttribute("http://schema/a", _
                "Namespace.In.A", _
                AssemblyName:="A")>
```

This does not seem to work, as any XAML instances of classes defined in A result in error "The type reference cannot find a public type named..." on compilation. I cannot find documentation or examples of the AssemblyName property of XmlnsDefinitionAttribute. Does anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `XmlnsDefinitionAttribute` must be defined in the assembly in question. So your XmlnsDefinitionAttribute must be in assembly A. You would place this in the AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: If it's used with the default constructor then yes it can be, and that does work, but my problem is I can't use it in assembly A as it has to stay in .NET v2, which does not contain XmlnsDefinitionAttribute. There is an optional parameter for XmlnsDefinitionAttribute called AssemblyName which makes it look like the attribute can be defined outside A but still refer to it, but I can't get it to work. I wonder if I am misunderstanding the point of AssemblyName.